# How to make a NSConstraint's Length change proportionately according to the device size

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, constants, ios10

I want to change the above constraint's length based on the device size, so my text is always at a proportional distance from the screen top.

[image]

Comment: You have to create @IBOutlet for that. Select your constraint line and create NSLayoutConstraint and set its constant. for example : 
`@IBOutlet var top : NSLayoutConstraint!`
`top.constant = 85`

Comment: @sadhu check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do proportional top space via adding screen height with adjusting multipliers in UI itself.

It will adjust top space automatically without doing any outlet constraints.

```
-> UIView

     -> UILabel (make hidden,for adjusting proportional top space)

         Constraints : top space - 8(default), width - 50(constant any value) , center horizantaly of parent UIView, equal height to parent UIView.
         Now modify your multipliers of proportional height to 0.2 (20% from your main view height) or 0.3(30 %).It will adjust based on screen size automatically.

     - > UILabel (Verification Code) Constraints : top space min 8 (default) & others...
```

[image]

Comment: How modifying the multipliers of equal height will affect the top space constraint which is set to  8, and what do you mean when you say 
  - UILabel (make hidden, for adjusting proportional top space)

Comment: @sadhu_sanjay first UILabel is invisible intermediate control between your top of view and second UILabel to adjust top space based on screen size.Just click height constraints of first label you can see multiplier property in right side panel,edit it set to 0.2 or 0.3..,you can see the adjustments

Comment: @sadhu_sanjay check my image.Dont forget to upvote.Thx

Comment: This is not the cleanest solution I was looking for, but this works. thanks accepted, upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `self.view.frame.height`.

Like this:

```
let height = self.view.frame.size.height
let constraint = CGFloat(Double(height) / 3)

yourConstraint.constant = constraint
```

Where `yourConstraint` is `@IBOutlet` for this constraint. You can add it like other items like `UILabel`, `UIView`. Just drag and drop it to your code.

Hope it helps

Comment: This should work, thanks. is there no way through storyboard? like when you can set a label's height based on some other view, using multiplier.

Comment: @sadhu_sanjay I have never met this solution, but maybe you can. I'm doing it this way:)

Comment: @sadhu_sanjay If my answer helped, accept it please (press jackdaw). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First create a IBOutlet for the constraint.

let's your constraint name is myConstraint. Now if you want the the distance of the verification code to be 20% from top
the you can use following code:

```
var parentFrameHeight = self.view.frame.height
myConstraint.constant = parentFrameHeight*(0.2)
```